# Trying to use EWS in Android App. Could not load Assembly 'System.Directory' Services

Tags: exchangewebservices

I want to create an Android App and get a list of rooms from our Exchange2010 Server. For that wanted to use EWS(Exchange Web Services). I tried installing the newest Version(2.2.0) of EWS through NuGet, but it fails with:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v5.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Since I wasn't able to resolve this issue, I tried the outdated Version of EWS(1.2.0), which I was able to install. I made some basic code for testing and when trying to Build I get the Error:

> Could not load assembly 'System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

After that, I added a reference to System.DirectoryServices.dll. Now I can Build the App. When trying to debug though, the App pops up in the Emulator and closes again, then I get the Error:

> Could not load assembly 'System.DirectoryServices' during startup registration.

I am using Visual Stuido Enterprise 2017 on Windows 10(latest Update).
Does Anyone have an ide what i can do to make this work? I also tried different Android Version as Target Platform, but none worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using EWS with .NET Core as the target framework. I uninstalled the incorrect version and installed the .NETStandard version. The command for the Visual Studio Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.NETStandard -Version 1.1.0
```

For more info: 
https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, even though it's such an old post. I will try this out, hopefully i can get it to work...